# PPTP VPN connection always connects successfully in Mac OS X/windows but drops after 2 minute in iPad or it doesn't connect al all!

Tags: ipad, vpn

I've a big problem with using iPad's VPN connection. When I use the same VPN connection (PPTP) configuration parameters in my Mac OS X Snow Leopard or my windows XP (Bootcamp), it works flawlessly but when I define the same connection in my iPad, connection drops in about 1 or 2 minutes (some times) and most of the time, it Doesn't Connect at all.
I'm using iPad 3G with iOS 4.2.1 and my iPad is not jail-broken.

I've tried so hard to make it work in an stable manner but not found any solution yet. (I should have put encryption level to No-Encryption in Mac and Windows otherwise it won't connect in my desktop operating systems. It is a host-related issue and I'm binding to that).

I'm sure there is no technical problem in my iPad's hardware and this problem also exists in my friend's iPad too. Our devices work perfectly with 3G and Wifi connections.

Your answers are really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally realized that if I redefine VPN connection using L2TP, the problem would be completely disappeared.